# Which namespace does contain the declaration of this friend function?

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, lookup, argument-dependent-lookup

The `friend` function below is not found by ordinary lookup (§7.3.1.2/3), but is found by ADL (§3.4.2/4 second bullet point), so the code compiles and executes normally ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8b8ce64b481fcd8)). But the function `f` isn't declared in any namespace. For example, if you try replacing the call `f(x);` by any of these calls `::f(x);`, `A::f(x);` or `A::X::f(x);`, the code will not compile. Which namespace does contain the declaration of this friend function? Does the Standard say anything about this?

```
#include <iostream>
namespace A {
    class X {
        int i;
        friend void f(X x) { std::cout << x.i << '\n'; }
    public:
        X():i(101){}
    };
}

int main()
{
    A::X x;
    f(x);
}
```

Comment: The Standard says lots about this.  Briefly, the function `f` is a member of `A`, but its declaration is not.

Comment: Using a qualified name suppresses argument-dependent lookup - which is the only lookup capable of finding a name declared in a friend declaration. This is why `f(x)` works but `A::f(x)` doesn't, even though `f` is a member of namespace `A`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Could you give a reference for this? Would that be §3.4.2/1?

Comment: Yes, that would be **3.4.2/1** When the postfix-expression in a function call (5.2.2) is an **unqualified-id**, other namespaces not considered
during the usual unqualified lookup (3.4.1) may be searched... Emphasis mine.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Does the Standard say that `f` is a member of `namespace A` in this circunstance?

Comment: **7.3.1.2/3** says that. You've asked this question before.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I forgot about this. You're right. But I'll have to accept Vlad's answer, which I believe came before your comment. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the C++ Standard

11.3 Friends

> 6 A function can be defined in a friend declaration of a class if and
>   only if the class is a non-local class (9.8), the function name is
>   unqualified, and **the function has namespace scope**.  [ Example:

```
class M { friend void f() { } // definition of global f, a friend of M,
                              // not the definition of a member function
};
```

> —end example ]

Amd the other quote (7.3.1 Namespace definition)

> 3 Every name first declared in a namespace is a member of that
>   namespace. If a friend declaration in a non-local class first declares
>   a class, function, class template or function template98 the friend is
>   a member of the innermost enclosing namespace. **The friend declaration
>   does not by itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup (3.4.1)
>   or qualified lookup (3.4.3). [ Note: The name of the friend will be
>   visible in its namespace if a matching declaration is provided at
>   namespace scope (either before or after the class definition granting
>   friendship). —end note ]** If a friend function or function template is
>   called, its name may be found by the name lookup that considers
>   functions from namespaces and classes associated with the types of the
>   function arguments (3.4.2). If the name in a friend declaration is
>   neither qualified nor a template-id and the declaration is a function
>   or an elaborated-type-specifier, the lookup to determine whether the
>   entity has been previously declared shall not consider any scopes
>   outside the innermost enclosing namespace. [ Note: The other forms of
>   friend declarations cannot declare a new member of the innermost
>   enclosing namespace and thus follow the usual lookup rules. —end note
>   ]

I would like to mention that enclosing a function name in parentheses suppresses the argument-dependent lookup.

For this code

```
int main()
{
    A::X x;
    ( f )(x);
}
```

function f will not be found.

Comment: Why then A::f(x) doesn't compile?

Comment: @Angew, @ChairmanMao: per **3.4.2/1** using a qualified name suppresses argument-dependent lookup - which is the only kind of lookup that can find `f`.